# Merging and summing multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, array, php5, iteration

I've found myself today really struggling with this subject and I'm pretty sure that there must be a better way to do this.

First of all my arrays have the same layout, I need to merge them and **sum every value by *domain***.

Let me give you an example:

```
$array[0]['X1']['Y1'] = 1;
$array[0]['X1']['Y2'] = 2;
$array[0]['INFO']['DOMAIN'] = 'example1.com';

$array[1]['X1']['Y1'] = 1;
$array[1]['X1']['Y2'] = 2;
$array[1]['INFO']['DOMAIN'] = 'example1.com';

$array[2]['X1']['Y1'] = 2;
$array[2]['X1']['Y2'] = 5;
$array[2]['INFO']['DOMAIN'] = 'example2.com';

$array[3]['X1']['Y1'] = 2;
$array[3]['X1']['Y2'] = 5;
$array[3]['INFO']['DOMAIN'] = 'example2.com';
```

I need to produce the following new array:

```
$mergedArray[0]['X1']['Y1'] = 2;
$mergedArray[0]['X1']['Y2'] = 4;
$mergedArray[0]['INFO']['DOMAIN'] = 'example1.com'; 

$mergedArray[1]['X1']['Y1'] = 4;
$mergedArray[1]['X1']['Y2'] = 10;
$mergedArray[1]['INFO']['DOMAIN'] = 'example2.com';
```

I'm using the following code to achieve this (forgive me for the bad namings).

```
foreach($array as $subKey => $subValue) {
    foreach($subValue as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($key2=='DOMAIN' && !isset($merged[$value2])) {
                $merged[$value2] = $subValue;
            } else if ($key2=='DOMAIN' && isset($merged[$value2])) {
                foreach($subValue as $key3=>$value3) {
                    foreach($value3 as $key4=>$value4) {
                        if($key4!='DOMAIN') 
                            $merged[$value2][$key3][$key4] += $value4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I improve this piece of code?

Comment: Where does this data come from? Do you have control of the input or output format?

Comment: will the keys always be like the keys in the example (i.e. `X1`, `X2`, `INFO`, `DOMAIN`) ? Would the order of keys ever be different?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that the format will be consistent, you could remove one `foreach` loop and extract the domain to use as the key of the merged array, and also only either set the sub array (with keys `X1`, `Y1` and `Y2`) or add to the sub array items.

```php
foreach($array as $subArray) {
    if (isset($subArray['INFO']) && isset($subArray['INFO']['DOMAIN'])) {
        $domainKey = $subArray['INFO']['DOMAIN'];
        if (!isset($merged[$domainKey])) {
            $merged[$domainKey] = $subArray;
        }
        else { // could add conditionals to ensure X1 is set on $subArray
            foreach($subArray['X1'] as $key => $value) {
                $merged[$domainKey]['X1'][$key] += $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[See it in action in this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/kl3Knb5V4kDawhMD).

A functional approach could also be employed by using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce):

```php
$merged = array_reduce($array, function($cumulative, $subArray) {
    if (isset($subArray['INFO']) && isset($subArray['INFO']['DOMAIN'])) {
        $domainKey = $subArray['INFO']['DOMAIN'];
        if (!isset($cumulative[$domainKey])) {
            $cumulative[$domainKey] = $subArray;
        }
        else { // could add conditionals to ensure X1 is set on $subArray
            foreach($subArray['X1'] as $key => $value) {
                $cumulative[$domainKey]['X1'][$key] += $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $cumulative;
}, []);
```

[See it in action in this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/PPyy4h1EL8KEv6Ro)